# Addressing a user details when my consumer class has one to one relation with User model

Tags: python, django, model

In my application I have created a `Consumer` class which keeps data in Django `User` class and adds other characteristics in the fields create by me. The `Consumer` class is connected to `User` in one to one relationship. I am able to post the data.

But now I need to search and retrieve information based on the `username` received in a request.  I am not able to search the `Consumer` class based on the `username`. Please advise how I achieve this.

My code is given below

```
class Consumer(models.Model):
        user= models.OneToOneField(User)
        company=models.CharField(max_length=64)
        street1=models.CharField(max_length=64)
        street2=models.CharField(max_length=64)
        city=models.CharField(max_length=64)
        state=models.CharField(max_length=64)
        country=models.CharField(max_length=64)
```

I am trying to get a record as below

```
def user_page(request, username):
    consumer=get_object_or_404(Consumer, username=username) # locate record
```

I get the following error

```
Cannot resolve keyword 'username' into field
```

I tried `User.username=username` as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

avoid using User.username. Replace . with double underscores __ 
try this instead.

```
def user_page(request, username):
    consumer=get_object_or_404(Consumer, user__username=username)
```

Answer (score 2):

You probably mean something like this: `consumer = get_object_or_404(Consumer, user__username=username)`